# Making PostgreSQL create directory for new tablespace

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

i would like to be able to do something like

```
CREATE TABLESPACE bob location 'C:\a\b\c\d\e\f\bob'
```

without needing to create all the directory tree beforehand.
this is because i have java code that creates tablespaces on the fly and i would like to be able to run it on a separate machine (so it couldnt mkdir() or anything).

is there any sort of postgres configuration that would allow me to make postgres create the appropriate directory tree by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try do `mkdir` directly in postgres stored procedure using [PL/sh](http://plsh.projects.pgfoundry.org/) or any of your favorite PL/* languages that are available for PostgreSQL

Comment: could you please point me to info on how i can do this using the built-in pl/pgsql ? i cant install any extensions on the db unfortunately, and the posgres docs for pl/pgsql only talk about dealing with tables

Comment: I believe that PL/pgSQL is for data manipulation only. You could try to write your function in C (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/xfunc-c.html) - it needs no extensions and directly supported by postgresql

Comment: You can't do it in pl/pgsql but you can with pm/perlu or pl/pythonu, both of which preinstalled.